# using a method invoker in an if statement

Tags: c#, multithreading, listbox, method-invocation

what i am trying to do is check whether an item in a list box is selected.

The method is being run on a separate thread so i would need to use a method invoker i believe.

```
string list = "";
lbxList.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { list = lbxList.SelectedItem.ToString(); }));

if (list != null)
{
 //do something
}
```

this code will blow up if the selected item is null because the string list wont hold it, so i would need a way to combine the top 2 lines into an if statement checking for null.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do:

```
string list = "";
lbxList.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
{
    if (lbxList.SelectedItem != null)
        list = lbxList.SelectedItem.ToString();
}));

//do something
```

Just place the if-statement inside the anonymous method.

Note that `.ToString` is *highly unlikely* to ever return `null` for anything, the [documentation of `object.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) states that overriding types should implement the method to return a *meaningful* value. Since we already know that `.SelectedItem` is not null, checking for null is not really necessary. You can leave it in if you really want, but if you're afraid that `.ToString` should return null, I would instead change the code to this:

```
string list = "";
lbxList.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
{
    if (lbxList.SelectedItem != null)
        list = lbxList.SelectedItem.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
}));

//do something
```

Comment: It will *probably* never be null. See my updated answer. There is no built-in guarantee that `.ToString` won't return null. It is highly unlikely, but *never* is such an absolute and strong word.